# Setting the context of a textview array

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-activity, android-context

How do i apply a context to a textview array?

```
TextView[] textView = new TextView[3];

for (int cell = 0; cell < 3; cell++){
    textView[cell].setText("-");
}
```

Apparently, this error gets thrown:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

If this was not a textview **array**, adding the activity **context** as a **parameter** when calling the constructor would render the object not null, solving my issue:

```
for (int cell = 0; cell < 3; cell++){
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText("-");
}
```

Where, `context = getActivity().getApplicationContext()`

How do i set the context **parameter** for the textview array? What i want is dynamic variable names for each textview so i can call the individual textviews respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create object before calling method.
Try this:

```
TextView[] textView = new TextView[3];

for (int cell = 0; cell < 3; cell++) {
    textView[cell] = new TextView(context);
    textView[cell].setText("-");
}
```

Comment: There we go. It looks redundant instantiating another textview. Apparently that is a child object and a different method instance.

Comment: When you create array, objects of this array aren't created. You should create them after

Answer (score 0):

I hope below code would help you out regarding context for array of views. First you will just create array but before using it you will have to create object using new keyword.

```
LinearLayout rootview = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootview);

ArrayList<String> words= new ArrayList<>();     

words.add("One"); words.add("two"); words.add("three"); words.add("four"); words.add("five"); words.add("six"); words.add("seven"); words.add("eight"); words.add("nine"); words.add("ten");

    int index=0;
    while(index<words.size()){

        TextView [] textViews = new TextView[words.size()];
        textViews[index] = new TextView(this);

        textViews[index].setText(words.get(index));
        rootview.addView(textViews[index]);
        index++;
    }
```